# Polar gridlines on a Cartesian scatter plot

Tags: matlab

I have a script to create scatter plots (using `gscatter`) based on x-y data (discrete data points, not continuous) produced by another script. Since these data points are actually the locations of certain objects in a circular space, adding polar grid lines will make the plots more meaningful.

Does anyone know how to show polar grid lines on a Cartesian scatter plot, or am I better off using polar plots?

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the `pol2cart` function to generate the polar grid lines.
For example:

```
function DrawGridLines
    x = randn(10);
    y = randn(10);
    figure;scatter(x(:),y(:));
    hold on ;
    for angle =  0:20:(360-20)
        [x1,y1] = pol2cart(  angle / 180 * pi , [0 2]);
        plot(x1,y1,'r')
    end

    for rho  =  0:0.1:2
        [x1,y1] = pol2cart(  0:0.01:2*pi , rho);
        plot(x1,y1,'b')
    end
    axis equal
end
```

[image]

Comment: (A quick reply to my own question)

Just after I posted the question, I thought of superimposing my scatter plot on a polar plot showing a unit circle.

t = 0:.01:2*pi;
polar(t,ceil(sin(t)),'--k')
hold on
gscatter(xs,ys,gs,'kkkkkk','o+^s*d',8,'on')

That worked as I wanted.
Thanks for everyone's attention.
Hurol Aslan

Comment: Correction: an empty polar plot using sin(0*t) worked better.

Answer (score 2):

I once made this script for drawing a polar coordinate system on top of a regular plot. Perhaps it can be useful for you. It is based on [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9471-polar-scatter-plot/content/scatplot.m) script but simplified to only draw the coordinate system and no data. If this wasn't what you were looking for, check out the linked script, perhaps it can help as well.

Be sure to tweak the radius as needed! I usually disable the axis but it's up to you to fix that if you need another look :)

```
R=6000; %radius
S=10;   %num circ.lines
N=10;   %num ang.lines

sect_width=2*pi/N;    
offset_angle=0:sect_width:2*pi-sect_width;

%------------------
r=linspace(0,R,S+1);
w=0:.01:2*pi;

clf %remove if needed

hold on
axis equal
for n=2:length(r)

    plot(real(r(n)*exp(j*w)),imag(r(n)*exp(j*w)),'k--')

end


for n=1:length(offset_angle)

    plot(real([0 R]*exp(j*offset_angle(n))),imag([0 R]*exp(j*offset_angle(n))),'k-')

end
%------------------
```

[image: Result from script]